# How to get rid of accents just with CSS

Tags: html, css, text, semantics

Without using JS, I wanted to *remove accents with CSS* so the HTML continues semantically correct while **visually** achieving UPPERCASE without accents.

Example:

```css
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*sth here*/
}
```

```html
<h1>Fácil</h1>
```

Tks!

Comment: You mean you want to transform `Fácil` into `Facil` right?

Comment: You can't, with only using css, you can do uppercase, lowercase and capitalize....see this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the `line-height` and use `overflow:hidden` but pay attention when using a different `font-family` you may need another value:

```css
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0.75em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Fácil é â ä</h1>
<h1 style="font-size:25px">Fácil é â ä</h1>
<h1 style="font-size:18px">Fácil é â ä</h1>
```

With another `font-family`:

```css
h1 {
  font-family:arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0.87em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Fácil é â ä</h1>
<h1 style="font-size:25px">Fácil é â ä</h1>
<h1 style="font-size:18px">Fácil é â ä</h1>
```

Comment: Don't understand the downvote here, this might be the only way in CSS

Comment: @RaymondNijland some users don't like *hacks* even if it's what the OP asked for but they are free ;)

Comment: Is there any info on how this hack is working?

Comment: @ChristosLytras check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978512/8620333

Comment: This is not working with the greek accents as they are not position over the letter but to the side. I guess a javascript would worked better